# Update web service / JSON data periodically for iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, json, xcode, parse-platform

I am creating a currency converter app that converts the currency exchange rates for over 165 countries. The currency rates fluctuate daily. I am trying to find a way to automatically pull JSON data every hour from (http://www.getexchangerates.com/api/latest.json) and send it to my back end stored on Parse.com. My app will then retrieve the data from parse when ever the user presses a UIbutton called "Update". I am not to familiar with JavaScript or PHP. What is the best way for me to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach, depending on the reach of your audience would be to have your client make the request to the API directly and just parse the data and display it. I know this isn't answering your question directly but it's an alternate solution. At least it could be quicker to get something up and running and you could change to your server cached solution later on.

Comment: I started off using that approach. Then I found out that www.openexchangerates.org only allows 1000 free API request per month. I don't want to pay $15/month for a free app. I'm expecting to have at least 20,000 API requests per month. My solution was going to be to create a web service that pulls the data every hour from www.openexchangerates.org and stores it on parse.com database. That would be only 24 API requests per day, approx. 720 per month. Then my app would connect to parse.com to receive data since parse has unlimited API requests.